# cmake not building when installed with homebrew

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew

I'm trying to install cmake with homebrew using `brew install cmake`, but it is throwing an error that I do not understand.

here's some of the log

```
[ 99%] Building CXX object Source/CMakeFiles/CTestLib.dir/CTest/cmCTestCVS.cxx.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object Source/CMakeFiles/CTestLib.dir/CTest/cmCTestSVN.cxx.o
[100%] Building CXX object Source/CMakeFiles/CTestLib.dir/CTest/cmCTestBZR.cxx.o
[100%] Building CXX object Source/CMakeFiles/CTestLib.dir/CTest/cmCTestGIT.cxx.o
[100%] Building CXX object Source/CMakeFiles/CTestLib.dir/CTest/cmCTestHG.cxx.o
[100%] Building CXX object Source/CMakeFiles/CTestLib.dir/CTest/cmCTestP4.cxx.o
Linking CXX static library libCTestLib.a
[100%] Built target CTestLib
make: *** [all] Error 2
Error: cmake 3.0.1 did not build
```

Any ideas? I'm on osx yosemite beta 5.

Comment: Can you post the link returned by `brew gist-logs --config --doctor cmake`? A similar issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/31450) and the resolution was to make sure to use Xcode 6 with Yosemite.

Comment: @TimSmith Here's the link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0351796569dfc6e8d4f4

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a 32-bit-only zlib installed to /usr/local?

The fatal error is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0351796569dfc6e8d4f4#file-02-make-L373

`lipo -info /usr/local/lib/libz.1.2.5.dylib` will confirm the diagnosis if you don't see "x86_64" in the output. (Compare to `lipo -info /usr/lib/libz.dylib`, which should give you "x86_64 i386".) The quickest answer is to delete /usr/local/lib/libz.1.2.5.dylib and /usr/local/lib/libz.a unless you're sure you have a good reason to have them there.

(Beyond that, your `brew doctor` output is a little scary. Running `brew prune` will safely get rid of a lot of broken symlinks. You have a lot of other libraries installed to `/usr/local` that will conflict with things Homebrew might install later or mask system libraries, like the problem you're having with zlib here.)

Comment: I had the same problem, and this solved it for me. Thanks!